# Why relativity exists?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Found this article on the internet on why relativity exists.

http://kenneth-chan.com/physics/why-relativity-exists/

Basically, the author is saying that the speed of light is constant because our perception is dependent on the speed of light (i.e. electromagnetic phenomenon). So when light slows down, so does our perception of time and therefore the speed of light stays constant.

I am not an academic or have enough knowledge about physics to judge the validity of this theory myself, so I want to know if this theory has been proven wrong and why? Because to me the theory makes sense.

I can't find any more articles related to the author or any such articles. If this theory has been accepted, can someone give me some links to related relevant papers/articles?

Comment: "*our perception is dependent on the speed of light*" I think it's more the speed of causality, and the speed of light is the speed of causality. So not so much our perception is dependent on the speed of light, but our perception (or rather, how fast things happen in general) are depend on the speed of causality.

Comment: The speed of electromagnetic transmission is **not** the speed of light. It is equal to the speed of light **in a vacuum** but our brains are not a vacuum. Well, mine isn't - I can't speak for Kenneth Chan.

Comment: Ha! Is one allowed in a comment to express delight at a waspish witticism?

Comment: Vishal, did the fact that you could not find any linked articles not suggest anything to you? The article is empty nonsense.

Comment: One might as well claim the speed of sound will be invariant because we hear sound. But it's not. (Besides, both speeds vary by medium.)

Answer (score 4):

It is spurious nonsense. Here is one simple refutation of his thesis.

If the speed of light (in a vacuum) varied, we would find different light rays travelling at different speeds. This never happens, not in Michelson-Morley and not in a thousand thousand other variegated situations, therefore the speed of light does not vary. (Light does slow down when passing through dense materials, but this is not a Relativistic effect, it is plain old Maxwell's equations and the properties of the material)

Einstein pulled the justification of his theory out of some quite complicated maths, famously also deriving $E = mc^2$. Chan plays sophistry with just one of the thousands of experimental setups that validate Special Relativity, he would need to tackle the maths head-on to demonstrate that he can deal with all the others. Yet he appeals principally to eye-boggling, with not an equation in sight; he is not doing physics, he is just pouring nonsense onto the Internet.

In this context it is interesting to recall that Michelson and Morley each made many subsequent experiments. A colleague of Morley's, Dayton C. Miller, long rebelled against the finding but was ultimately defeated by the weight of experimental evidence. If he could not undermine it, what chance a practitioner of rhetoric with nary an equation to his name?